# How to pass php functional parameters from python script and get output?

Tags: python, php

I'm working on a python plugin & it needs to retrive some data from php script,
As I tried below I can retrive php output as shell command,

But I need to call **start()** function from my **python** script by passing values as **start(10,15)**

Is there a possible way to call **start()** **php** function with parameters from **python** script ?

PHP Script:

```php
<?php

function start($height, $width) {
    
    return $height*$width;
}

echo start(10,15);  // #1

?>
```

Python Script:

```py
import subprocess

result = subprocess.run(
    ['php', './check1.php'],    # program and arguments
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  # capture stdout
    check=True               # raise exception if program fails
)
print(result.stdout)         # result.stdout contains a byte-string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass command-line arguments to a PHP script.  See https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

PHP:

```
...
echo start($argv[1], $argv[2]);
```

Python:

```
result = subprocess.run(
    ['php', './check1.php', '10', '15'],
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
    check=True
)
```

Comment: hi Sir,if we have multiple functions like start1( ) ,start2( ) ,how can we select & pass values to specific function..

Comment: If your main code is in PHP, why not just run PHP?  Why involve Python at all?  You can certainly pass a "command" word as one of the arguments.

Comment: the reason was plugins which I try to implement based on python but core system which I try to retrieve data is PHP,anyway thank you for your comment sir,I found a way..